# Array to string conversion SOAP

Tags: php, api, soap

So i have the following soap function , i call it in my code a few times , but it gives me the notice of an array to string conversion on line 5.

```
public function soap($login,$functionName,$api_key,$params,$optional = array(),$n=1){
        try{
            $client = new SoapClient('http://4dealer.ru/soap/?WSDL');
            $hash = md5($login . $functionName . md5($api_key));
            $result = $client->$functionName($login,$hash,$params,$optional);
        }catch (SoapFault $E){
            if($n<3){
                sleep(1);
                return $this->soap($login,$functionName,$api_key,$params,$optional,$n+1);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

can you put your call code ? the 5 line is:

$client->$functionName

you should see what are you passing to method that make this error